# Part List Layout. How to implement a realtionship with a table itself?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sequelize.js

so I want to build a intventory Management database.

My schema looks like this:

[Database Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mv2yr.png)

An Itemclass (screwdriver, hammer, measuring device,...) can have many items (screwdriver1, screwdriver2,...)

Everything is fine and working as expected. But now i want to create a feature for part lists. So basically I want to create a Itemclass (e.g Tools for XY) which include other Itemclasses (screwdriver, hammer,...)

I might overthink this, but i dont find a working solution. Anybody got some tips?

This is the result I actually expect:

[My Thoughts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKCUw.png)

Comment: Please don't link to images - add all information to your question as editable text, formatted appropriately. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 0):

If you add a parent_id field to your item_class table that is a foreign key to the id field of item_class table, you can easily achieve this. When you want to add an item_class under another just set the child item_class’s parent_id to its parent’s id.

You can then use `ltree` in PostgreSQL or `CONNECT BY` in Oracle to create hierarchical queries. Here is a source for ltree: [POSTGRESQL: SPEEDING UP RECURSIVE QUERIES AND HIERARCHICAL DATA](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/postgresql-speeding-up-recursive-queries-and-hierarchic-data/?gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAiAtt2tBhBDEiwALZuhAGl3FlWDG0o2QqxG37OkKh0Z19Q79bQskElND6Z_frMRAJL7DMJMzhoCTp8QAvD_BwE)

Answer (score 0):

While studying the answer from Bahattin Ungormus, and looking for self-erences if found my solution.

Model:

```
ItemClass.belongsToMany(ItemClass, {as: "Children", through: "ItemClassChildren", timestamps: false })
```

And the query for this:

```
    const results = await ItemClass.findAll({
    include: {
        model: ItemClass,
        as: "Children",
    },
```